# Maya Python scripting menu alignment

Tags: python, scripting, maya

I'm creating a simple window in Maya using cmds python scripting. Could you please tell is it possible to change menu placement or menu item placement from left to right.

Comment: do you mean right aligned? Or right-to-left text, like in Arabic or Hebrew?

Comment: I mean right aligned. In right side of the window.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a simple **window**, you can set its alignment in the window's layout, for example consider this window with a columnLayout:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.window()
cmds.columnLayout(columnAlign="right") # all child elements of this layout will be right-aligned;
cmds.button()
cmds.button()
cmds.button()
cmds.showWindow()
```

However, if you're creating a custom **menu** in your custom window or in Maya's main window using cmds.menu and cmds.menuItem, then you cannot change the alignment of the menu or its menuItem content, since these don't have a layout.

You can look up alignment for varous layouts in [Maya's technical documentation](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2017/ENU/).